# Convert a JSON object to Tree Structure in PDF format

Tags: json, pdf

I want to convert a JSON object to PDF such that the resultant PDF contains Tree representation of JSON. Please help me with any online utility or tool for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ObjectMapper in JAVA, then create the PDF File of it.or you can use this link for online :https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/json-to-pdf